Parameter 0 of constructor in 'Controller' required a bean of type 'service' that could not be found. Adding annotation and componentscan doesn't work
It's multy-module app. user-app is working well but when I pushed my work from one-module project Interllij gave me this error. Everythink was working before I added modules.
Trying to make it working.
Project sructure
Error
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-17T22:15:34.760+07:00 ERROR 4276 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.service.CategoryService required a bean of type 'ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.repository.CategoryRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.repository.CategoryRepository' in your configuration.

CategoryService:
package ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException;
import ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.dto.CategoryDto;
import ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.dto.CreateUpdateCategoryDto;
import ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.dto.HierarchyDto;
import ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.dto.converter.CategoryConverter;
import ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.entity.CategoryEntity;
import ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.repository.CategoryRepository;
import ru.tsu.hits.forum.Message.repository.MessageRepository;
import ru.tsu.hits.forum.Topic.repository.TopicRepository;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.dto.converter.CategoryConverter.categoryToDto;
import static ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.dto.converter.CategoryConverter.categoryToEntity;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CategoryService {
    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    private final TopicRepository topicRepository;
    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;

CategoryRepository:
package ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ru.tsu.hits.forum.Category.entity.CategoryEntity;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
@Component
public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<CategoryEntity, String> {
    List<CategoryEntity> findAllByParentCategoryOrderByName(String id);

    @Query("select c from CategoryEntity c where c.name LIKE %:name%")
    List<CategoryEntity> findAllByNameIgnoreCase(@Param("name") String name);
}

Nothing from another answers on StackOverflow helped.
